# How do you drop a PostgreSQL database with a carriage return in the name?

Tags: postgresql, special-characters

Somehow, via a restore done through code I ended up with a database with the following name (simulated output from \l command)

```
       Name       |
------------------|
 \r              +|
 DATABASE_NAME    |
```

I would like to be able to drop it, but I have no idea how to construct the name properly to include the carriage return when specified via DROPDB or DROP DATABASE commands.

If I can't drop it - can I change the owner to hide it - doesn't that also involve specifying the name?

PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do $$
begin
    execute format('drop database %I', E'\rDATABASE_NAME');
end;
$$
```

Rahul's answer should be

```
drop database U&"\000ADATABASE_NAME";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that mistake. I have edited my answer after seeing your answer. Hope that's fine. Also, I feel you should have commented the same in my answer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  The command that helped my in the end was: `alter database U&"\000A\000DDATABASE_NAME";`

Comment: this answer didn't work for me. i'm getting error 25001:
`[25001] ERROR: DROP DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string Where: SQL statement "DROP DATABASE " DATABASE"" PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at EXECUTE`

Answer (score 3):

Use `unicode` for line feed while dropping the database like below

```
drop database U&"\000ADATABASE_NAME";
```

You can as well `ALTER` the name like

```
alter database U&"\000ADATABASE_NAME" rename to "DATABASE_NAME_NEW";
```

Comment: to find out the correct prefix characters in the database name you can use the hex function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814220/925125
`SELECT hex(datname) FROM pg_database;`