# how to create a random color hex in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found this syntax in MySQL

```
SELECT concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6))
```

I can't use it as it is in PostgreSQL

Would you help me to convert that MySQL syntax to PostgreSQL syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813386/mysqls-hex-and-unhex-equivalent-in-postgres

Comment: i mean i can't convert this syntax
SELECT concat('#',SUBSTRING((lpad(hex(round(rand() * 10000000)),6,0)),-6))

Comment: @dwir182 could u help?

Comment: `concat('#', left(lpad(to_hex((random() * 10000000)::bigint), 6, '0'), 6))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works!! thank you soo much :D

Comment: I think you should post an answer. The comment from @a_horse_with_no_name works!